# Metadata accessor information was not found on Sybase 12 database

Tags: java, database, sybase

I am not able to get meta information for Sybase 12 database. I am using jconnect4 jar file. I am getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database. Please install the required tables as mentioned in the jConnect documentation.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleSQLE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried to use jconnect3 jar, sajsbc4 jar but not able to resolve this error. How can I solve this error?